# Помощь с VkontakteApi

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Если ли возможность подгрузить свой скрипт к сайту, используя API VK? Может прописав функцию в Хранимых процедурах? Приложение ВК интегрировано к сайту, до доступа к коду сайта нет. Нужно грузить скрипт из приложения

Comment: Что, где, почему?.. Вы хотите загрузить вконтакт какую то "хранимую процедуру" для того чтобы она выполнялась на сайте, к которому у вас нет доступа?.. Я правильно Вас понимаю? Это примерно также как просить банк дать вам деньги, которые вам не принадлежат...и при этом попросить вам их наличными принести домой, потому что у вас счета нет.

Comment: @МихаилРебров К сайту есть доступ. Сайт построен с помощью конструктора, в котором нельзя прописывать собственные скрипты, но можно интегрировать Ловец Лидов Вконтакте. Интеграцию сделал, теперь нужно как-то грузить скрипт через приложение ВК. Это сделать можно точно, работающие примеры видел